Vanishing of a Fourier transform for $|x|>1$
Show that
$$ 
\operatorname{g}\left(x\right) =
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}
{\rm e}^{-{\rm i}ux}\,\frac{4\sin^{2}\left(u/2\right)}{u^{2}}\,{\rm d}u
$$
vanishes when $|x| > 1$.

I have little idea how to approach this one.
Some naive attempts including differentiation under integral sign but couldn't quite finish.
It might have something to do with Fourier Inversion Formula ?.


The related Fourier inversion is $$\int\limits_{-1}^1 e^{i u x} \left(\left{\begin{array}{cc}
x+1 & -1\le x\leq 0 \
1-x & 0<x\le 1 \
\end{array}\right.\right) , dx.$$

By the simple Fourier integral, the inverse Fourier transform of the characterisc function of an interval is of the form $$\text{sinc}( a x)=\frac{\sin a x}{a x}.$$
The Fourier transform of a square of a function is the convolution square of the Fourier transform, yielding a triangle shape function by the elementary convolution of two characteristic functions.
$$f(x) =   \int_{-\infty}^\infty \ \chi_{ \left(-\frac{1}{2},\ \frac{1}{2}\right)}(u)\  * \  \chi_{\left( -\frac{1}{2}, \ \frac{1}{2}\right)}(x-u) \ du \ = \ \begin{cases}
 1-x & 0<x<1 \\
 x+1 & -1<x\leq 0
\end{cases}$$

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Hereafter, $\ds{\iverson{\cdots}}$ is an
Iverson Bracket.
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{\on{g}\pars{x}} & \equiv
\color{#44f}{{1 \over 2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}
\expo{-\ic ux}\,\,{\,4\sin^{2}\pars{u/2}\, \over u^{2}}\,\dd u}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}
\expo{-\ic ux}\,\,{\sin\pars{u/2} \over u/2}
{\sin\pars{u/2} \over u/2}\,\dd u
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\expo{-\ic ux}\ \times
\\ & \phantom{{1 \over 2\pi}\int}\pars{{1 \over 2}
\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{\ic\pars{u/2}p}\,\dd p}
\!\!\pars{{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{-\ic\pars{u/2}q}
\,\,\dd q}\!\dd u
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 4}\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\expo{-\ic\bracks{x\ -\ \pars{p\ -\ q}/2}u}\quad{\dd u \over 2\pi}\,\,\dd p\,\dd q
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 4}\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}
\delta\pars{x - {p - q \over 2}}\dd p\,\dd q
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 4}\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}
{\delta\pars{p - \bracks{2x + q}} \over 1/2}
\,\dd p\,\dd q
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}
\iverson{-1 < 2x + q < 1}\dd q
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}
\iverson{-1 - 2x < q < 1 - 2x}\dd q
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{\color{#44f}{\left\{\begin{array}{ccrcccl}
\ds{\phantom{-}x + 1} & \mbox{if} & \ds{-1} & \ds{<} & \ds{x} & \ds{\leq} & \ds{0}
\\[2mm]
\ds{-x + 1} & \mbox{if} & \ds{0} & \ds{<} & \ds{x} & \ds{<} & \ds{1}
\\[2mm] \ds{\phantom{-}0} && \mbox{otherwise} &&&&
\end{array}\right.}} \\ &
\end{align}
It has a  nice picture:

